# Full height image on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

How can place an image on website
I have album(horizontal) image. I needed place on mobile devices that image that height of image was full device height...And need avaliable horizontal scroll..
like that[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this the only element on your page? Please consider adding  more details.

Comment: @martynasma
This is an img...maybe in div

Comment: `overflow-x: auto` on this `img` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

**CSS-file**

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
.img-album {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.img-album > img {
    height:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="img-album">
    <img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/new-wallpaper-3.jpg" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmitriyBorisov/pjcL21u2/)